# Flutter http request returns error code 502, but same request in python returns http code 200

Tags: flutter, dart, http

When I debug this function I get the http error code 502:

```
Future<bool> checkSessionID(String sessionId) async {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://myurl.com");
  var myobj = {
    "session": sessionId,
  };
  
  HttpClient client = HttpClient(context: SecurityContext()..setTrustedCertificatesBytes(creds.key.codeUnits));
  
  var request = await client.postUrl(uri);
  request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
  request.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(myobj)));
  

  var response = await request.close();
  // encode response to json
  var json = jsonDecode(await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
  return json["status"];
}
```

but when I remove the JSON payload it returns code 200:

```
Future<bool> checkSessionID(String sessionId) async {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://myurl.com");
  var myobj = {
    "session": sessionId,
  };
  
  HttpClient client = HttpClient(context: SecurityContext()..setTrustedCertificatesBytes(creds.key.codeUnits));
  
  var request = await client.postUrl(uri);
  //request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
  //request.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(myobj)));
  

  var response = await request.close();
  // encode response to json
  var json = jsonDecode(await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
  return json["status"];
}
```

when I run this python code it works just fine:

```
url = 'https://myurl.com'
payload = {"session": session_id}

request = requests.post(url, json = payload, verify="cert.cer")
```

Am I encoding the json wrong in the dart code or what is my mistake?

Comment: Can you see what the server gets sent/print the requests when sending them and compare?

Comment: @Banana No, unfortunately I don't have access to the server.